# Wix v3.10 Boostrapper crashes on Windows 7 RTM

Tags: wix

On a 32 or 64 bit Windows 7 Pro (just RTM no updates), I create a bundle with the WiX Toolset (Visual Studio WIX Bootstrapper project) v3.10.0.1823 that outputs an executable.

If I install SP1, the bootstrapper works as intended.
If I install the custom MSI with my application (without dependencies) it works on RTM.

This was in the application event log:

Windows cannot access the file  for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program  because of this error.

Program: 
File:

The error value is listed in the Additional Data section.
User Action
1. Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again.
2. If the file still cannot be accessed and
    - It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be contacted.
    - It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer.
3. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command prompt, type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER.
4. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy.
5. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your administrator or computer hardware vendor for further assistance.

Additional Data
Error value: 00000000
Disk type: 0

Any thoughts on how I can the bootstrapper running on blank install of Windows 7 RTM?

Update:

Tried an empty Bootstrapper just referencing the package (MSI) for my application.  I can run the package for my application just fine standalone, just can't launch thru the bootstrap:

Is there a log file or something I can look at to provide more info?  To get around this, I'm going to try creating a MSI that does an OS check (requiring SP1 of Win 7) that wraps the Bootstrapper.exe.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Bundle Name="Bootstrapper1" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Me" UpgradeCode="d94220ca-b99f-4d1d-acec-024cfc65c898">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
    <Chain>
  <MsiPackage Id="MyPackage" SourceFile="<path to my package>" Name="MyPackage" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"  DisplayInternalUI="no" InstallCondition="VersionNT"  Visible ="yes" />     
</Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Comment: I was able to install WiX 3.10.0.1823 itself on an x64 Win7 Pro RTM (no updates).  Does it work for you on your test machine?  Are you getting any kind of log in %temp% when your bundle crashes?

Comment: Installing WiX works ok, and a normal Product based WiX generated MSI works ok.

Comment: Sorry, no logs in %temp%.  If there is a diagnostic flag I can pass the default Bootstrapper EXE to get more information, I can get that info.

To repo what:

1.  Install WiX v3.10 Toolset with Visual Studio 2015
2.  Create a Windows Installer XML:  Bootstrapper Project

Comment: Can you post your code for the Bootstrapper project?

Comment: If you're not getting any log in %temp%, then it must be failing very early.  I think the only thing to do is download the WiX debug symbols and debug it.  If you can put your bundle .exe somewhere I could try to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.  I created a WiX Bootstrapper Project in a new solution in VS2015, built it, and was able to install and uninstall it on a Win7 x64 Pro RTM VM with no updates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper1" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Me" UpgradeCode="ff6c5879-f9b6-4941-a769-3c51bca2a070">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="NetFx451Redist" SourceFile="path\to\testing.msi" />
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```